# python multiprocessing print / stdou to single file format issue

Tags: python, multiprocessing, stdout, python-multiprocessing

I am processing a huge file using multiprocess module. I go through each line do some process and print / stdout it into another file. The issue is that I at times get 2 different lines printed on a single line. I have locks in place even then I see the same issue. How do I fix this ?

e.g

```
output received:
0,0.784207850012,0.215792149988,1,B5E326C7,0.257956186525,0.742043813475,1,UP87859

expected output:
0,0.784207850012,0.215792149988,1,B5E326C7
0.257956186525,0.742043813475,1,UP87859
```

Code:

```
#global lock
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

def pred(line):
    u,seg,c,g,lab = line.strip().split(None,4)
    < #### DO SOMETHING ##### and generate p,pp0,pp1>
    if('null' not in lab):
        lock.acquire()
        sys.stdout.write(','.join(map(str, [p,pp0,pp1,1,u])) + '\n')
        lock.release()
    else:
        lock.acquire()
        sys.stdout.write(','.join(map(str, [p,pp0,pp1,1,u])) + '\n')
        lock.release()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(25,initializer=init, initargs=(l,))
    with open('file.csv') as source_file:
         results = pool.map(pred, source_file,1000)
```

Comment: What I would do is remove lock and write logs to the queue and flush every once in a while. Check https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues

Comment: Which operating system are you using?  On Windows, this code creates an entirely different `lock` in each process.

Comment: @vittore Thanks. I'll look into it.

Comment: @TimPeters I am on linux